# Preventing rapid clicks on a button and making a request using rxjava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have the following method that makes a request to get a pokemon from a endpoint.

I would like to prevent the user in making rapid requests by clicking quickly on the button that will invoke this method many times. I have used the throttle* methods and debounce.

Bascially, what I am looking for if the user rapidly clicks on the button within 300 milliseconds duration it should accept the last click in that duration. However, what i am experiencing is that all requests are being made. i.e. if the user rapidly clicks 3x within that duration I still get 3 requests.

```
   fun getPokemonDetailByName(name: String) {
        pokemonDetailInteractor.getPokemonDetailByName(name)
            .subscribeOn(pokemonSchedulers.background())
            .observeOn(pokemonSchedulers.ui())
            .toObservable()
            .throttleFirst(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .singleOrError()
            .subscribeBy(
                onSuccess = { pokemon ->
                    pokemonDetailLiveData.value = pokemon
                },
                onError = {
                    Timber.e(TAG, it.localizedMessage)
                }
            ).addTo(compositeDisposable)
    }
```

Comment: You ask a question, read answers for 2 weeks and then post a half answer of yourself and accepting that? I guess technically there is nothing wrong with what you've done, but, did you know in your own answer you may get an outdated version of pokemon if that response get delivered later? At least 2 answers tell you how to properly do this job. Please at least add a switchMap to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning RxBinding anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers.

However, I found a solution that works using RxBinding with debounce operator. I'm posting here as it could be useful to someone else.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PokemonViewHolder {
    binding = PokemonListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    val pokemonViewHolder = PokemonViewHolder(binding.root)

    pokemonViewHolder.itemView.clicks()
        .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribeBy(
            onNext = {
                val name = pokemonList[pokemonViewHolder.adapterPosition].name

                if(::pokemonTapped.isInitialized) {
                    pokemonTapped(name)
                }
            },
            onError = { Timber.e(it, "Failed to send pokemon request %s", it.localizedMessage) }
        ).addTo(compositeDisposable)

    return pokemonViewHolder
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> Bascially, what I am looking for if the user rapidly clicks on the
> button within 300 milliseconds duration it should accept the last
> click in that duration

to me sounds more like that debounce operator behaviour. From the documentation

> Debounce — only emit an item from an Observable if a particular
> timespan has passed without it emitting another item

you can see the marble diagram [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html)

Comment: I did try the debouce operator. However, I think it could be with setting the duration to a specific time. But I think you could be right with this case.

Answer (score 5):

```
private val subject = PublishSubject.create<String>()

init {
    processClick()
}

fun onClick(name: String) {
    subject.onNext(name)
}

private fun processClick() {
    subject
        .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .switchMap { getPokemonDetailByName(it) }
        .subscribe(
            { pokemonDetailLiveData.value = it },
            { Timber.e(TAG, it.localizedMessage) }
        )
}

private fun getPokemonDetailByName(name: String): Observable<Pokemon> =   
     pokemonDetailInteractor
        .getPokemonDetailByName(name)
        .subscribeOn(pokemonSchedulers.background())
        .observeOn(pokemonSchedulers.ui())
        .toObservable()
```

In your case, the `getPokemonDetailByName` creates a new subscription every time. Instead, send the click events to a `Subject`, create a single subscription to that stream and apply `debounce`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have posted  my answer as slightly modified version of yours. And this worked as expected. I have also posted my final answer which I think is best for my solution that uses RxBinding's library.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should handle click events as an observable so you can call debounce on clicks themselves. One way to achieve what you look for is to have a class creating an observable from the view being clicked:

```
public class RxClickObservable {

    public static Observable<String> fromView(View view, String pokemonName) {

        final PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                subject.onNext(pokemonName);
            }
        });

        return subject;
    }

}
```

and in activity/fragment:

```
RxClickObservable.fromView(binding.button, pokemonName)
        .subscribeOn(pokemonSchedulers.background())
        .observeOn(pokemonSchedulers.ui())
        .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .switchMap(pokemonName ->  pokemonDetailInteractor.getPokemonDetailByName(pokemonName))
        .subscribe(... );
```

**Update:** Thanks to Amit Shekhar for this article: [Implement Search Using RxJava Operators](https://blog.mindorks.com/implement-search-using-rxjava-operators-c8882b64fe1d)

Answer (score 3):

There is another interesting approach to achieve this *i.e.* **WatchDog**. The concept comes from electronics and hardware design. (to see more information about it, refer to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer))

The main point of a WatchDog is that the delegated job will be done if the WatchDog wouldn't reset until due time.

However, we can implement this concept as the following:

#### TimerWatchDog.kt

```
import java.util.*

/**
 * @author aminography
 */
class TimerWatchDog(private val timeout: Long) {

    private var timer: Timer? = null

    fun refresh(job: () -> Unit) {
        timer?.cancel()
        timer = Timer().also {
            it.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
                override fun run() = job.invoke()
            }, timeout)
        }
    }

    fun cancel() = timer?.cancel()

}
```

#### Usage:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment {

    private val watchDog = TimerWatchDog(300)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        button.setOnClickListener {
            watchDog.refresh {
                getPokemonDetailByName(name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, if the user clicks on the button relentlessly with an interval shorter than 300ms, the `getPokemonDetailByName(name)` wouldn't call. So, only the last click causes calling the function.

It's highly beneficial also where we have a search box that runs a query, based on the user input text. (*i.g.* adding a `TextWatcher` on the `EditText`) It leads to fewer api calls while the user is typing, consequently optimizing resource consumption.

Answer (score 3):

The `getPokemonDetailByName()` subscribes to a new stream every time it is called.

Instead of subscribing to a new stream every time, just provide a subject to send the data to and map it directly to a `LiveData` with [`LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveDataReactiveStreams#fromPublisher(org.reactivestreams.Publisher%3CT%3E)).

```
private val nameSubject = PublishSubject.create<String>()

val pokemonDetailLiveData = nameSubject.distinctUntilChanged()
                .observeOn(pokemonSchedulers.background())
                .switchMap(pokemonDetailInteractor::getPokemonDetailByName)
                .doOnError { Timber.e(TAG, it.localizedMessage) }
                .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
                .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
                .to(LiveDataReactiveStreams::fromPublisher)

fun getPokemonDetailByName(name: String) {
    nameSubject.onNext(name)
}
```

The `observeOn(pokemonSchedulers.background())` operator is needed as subjects handle subscriptions differently. The `onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())` ensures that only valid objects end up in the `LiveData`.

Like this only a single stream is subscribed to once the `pokemonDetailLiveData` is being observed. The `PublishSubject` ensures that only a user click triggers the update from the API and only a single API call is active at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone has complicated ways to create an observable out of a button click.  Rxjs seems to have a built-in way to do this from the very first [page](https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview):

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

fromEvent(document, 'click').subscribe(() => console.log('Clicked!'));
```

So take your subscription chain that includes the throttle, but start with the `fromEvent` method.  It turns an event into an observable for you.  (I'm not sure where you'd create this, but in C# we do it all in the class constructor.)

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the answer by @ckunder and slightly modified and works as expected.

```
    // Start listening for item clicks when viewmodel created
    init {
        observeOnItemClicks()
    }

    // remove clicks that are emitted during the 200ms duration. In the onNext make the actual request  
    private fun observeOnItemClicks() {
        subject
            .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeBy(
                onNext = { pokemonName ->
                    getPokemonDetailByName(pokemonName)
                },
                onError = { Timber.e(it, "Pokemon click event failed ${it.localizedMessage}")}
            )
            .addTo(compositeDisposable)
    }

// No need to change this as this will be called in the onNext of the subject's subscribeBy
fun getPokemonDetailByName(name: String) {
    shouldShowLoading.postValue(true)

    pokemonDetailInteractor.getPokemonDetailByName(name)
        .subscribeOn(pokemonSchedulers.background())
        .observeOn(pokemonSchedulers.ui())
        .subscribeBy(
            onSuccess = { pokemon ->
                shouldShowLoading.postValue(false)
                pokemonDetailLiveData.postValue(pokemon)
            },
            onError = {
                shouldShowLoading.value = false
                Timber.e(TAG, it.localizedMessage)
            }
        ).addTo(compositeDisposable)
}

// emit the name when the user clicks on an pokemon item in the list
fun onPokemonItemClicked(name: String) {
    subject.onNext(name)
}
```